# Lilypond: Can't create title for song

Tags: lilypond

The following displays only the book title.
I want a separate title for each score.
It shows the opus and piece, but not the title for that score.
What am I doing wrong? I'm basing this on [Creating titles headers and footers](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/creating-titles-headers-and-footers).

```
\version "2.18.2"
\book {
    \header {
        title = "book title"
    }
    \score {
        \header {
            title = "song title is missing"
            subtitle = "subtitle is missing"
            opus = "opus"
            piece = "yo"
        }
        \new Staff {
            \key f \major
            \time 6/4
            \clef treble
        } % Staff
    } % score
} % book
```

Answer (score 3):

You could force LilyPond to display all titles like with this `\paper` block:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\book {
\paper {print-all-headers = ##t}
    \header {
        title = "book title"
    }
    \score {
        \header {
            title = "song title is missing"
            subtitle = "subtitle is missing"
            opus = "opus"
            piece = "yo"
        }
        \new Staff {
            \key f \major
            \time 6/4
            \clef treble
        } % Staff
    } % score
} % book
```

You can see it [here on lilybin.com](http://lilybin.com/jqdl3q/366).

I have no idea why the default behavior is not to display the title, but fortunately you can always change the setting to what you like most.

Answer (score 2):

`bookpart` is another way, though if you want a one-off title and the part title to be in the `title` field then a leading title page and to use `title` for what I've placed in `subtitle` for each `bookpart` may be necessary:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\header {
    title = "book title"
}
\book {
    \bookpart {
        \header {
            subtitle = "part1"
            opus = "opus"
            piece = "yo"
        }
        \score {
            \new Staff {
                \key f \major
                \time 6/4
                \clef treble
            }
        }
    }
    \bookpart {
        \header {
            subtitle = "part2"
            opus = "opus"
            piece = "yo"
        }
        \score {
            \new Staff {
                \key f \major
                \time 6/4
                \clef treble
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From Lilypond's manual:

#### [4.1.6](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/other-paper-variables#miscellaneous-paper-variables) Miscellaneous `\paper` variables

> - `print-all-headers`
>
> ...this will print all headers for each `\score` in the output. Normally only the `piece` and `opus` header variables are printed. Default: `#f`.

#### [3.2.1](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/creating-titles-headers-and-footers#titles-explained) Titles explained:

> ...only `piece` and `opus` fields are printed by default in Score Titles unless the `\paper` variable, `print-all-headers`, is set to `#t`.

So, for an example that includes a book header and multiple score headers, that would look like this:

```
\book {

 \paper {
  print-all-headers = ##t
 }

 \header {
  title = "Title for book"
 }
 
 \score {
  %...music here...
  \header {
   title = "Title for first score"
  }
 }
 
 \score {
  %...music here...
  \header {
   title = "Title for second score"
  }
 }

}
```

That should do the trick.